# Pasting excel data into a blank DataGridView - Index out of range exception

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I have an excel sheet with the following:

[image]

So, what I am trying to achieve is copy this from Excel and paste it into a blank `DataGridView` view.

This is the code I have so far:

```
private void PasteClipboard(DataGridView myDataGridView)
{
    DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
        foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
        {
            string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];

                myDataGridView.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the code runs, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Am I approaching this task at hand incorrectly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging around, I found that I have to add columns first, then add a new row, get the row index of the newly created row, and then set the cell values.

Here's the updated code:

```
DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
{
    if (myDataGridView.RowCount > 0)
        myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

    if (myDataGridView.ColumnCount > 0)
        myDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

    bool columnsAdded = false;
    string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
    foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
    {
        string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

        if (!columnsAdded)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

            columnsAdded = true;
            continue;
        }

        myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

        using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = myDataGridView.Rows[myRowIndex])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here it is working:

[image]

Happy to accept criticisms and useful tips on improving this. **This code is quite slow...**

Comment: How would you be able to copy multiple sheets into the datagridview?

Comment: Awesome, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Perfect Code here: (write in button)

```
DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
{
    if (myDataGridView.RowCount > 0)
        myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

    if (myDataGridView.ColumnCount > 0)
        myDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

    bool columnsAdded = false;
    string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
    int j=0;
    foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
    {
        string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

        if (!columnsAdded)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

            columnsAdded = true;
            continue;
        }

        myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

        using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = myDataGridView.Rows[j])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
}
```

Modified from [Latheesan's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/22833914/).

Comment: How is this any different from my answer? It almost look identical also... Did you just copy and paste my answer?

Comment: No sir. your code-paste last line only. i just edit int j=0 and increases that value for paste all value of copied

Comment: What significant improvement does your edit provide?

Answer (score 5):

I know it's some years later, but I was looking for a solution for this problem and found BASA's modification of Latheesan's code. It only worked partially, so modifying it, I would like to add this solution for future browsers:

```
private void Paste(DataGridView d)
    {
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r");
            int j = 0;
            try { j = d.CurrentRow.Index; } catch { }
            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                DataGridViewRow r = new DataGridViewRow();
                r.CreateCells(d, pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' }));
                d.Rows.Insert(j, r);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It helped me. Just got an error that there should be columns in `DataGridView`

Comment: Excellent Work!

Answer (score 3):

Have your gridview columns defined, if not you have to define the columns first.

```
private void PasteClipboard(DataGridView myDataGridView)
{
    DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
        foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
        {
            string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow())
            {
                myDataGridViewRow = (DataGridViewRow) myDataGridView.RowTemplate.Clone();
                for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];

                myDataGridView.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IF not definced columns

```
private void PasteClipboard(DataGridView myDataGridView)
{
    //Create COlumns in datagridView
    myDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col1", "Col1");
    myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col2", "Col2");
    myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col3", "Col3");
    myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col4", "Col4");

    DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
    {
        string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
        foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
        {
            string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = new DataGridViewRow())
            {
                myDataGridViewRow = (DataGridViewRow) myDataGridView.RowTemplate.Clone();
                for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                    myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];

                myDataGridView.Rows.Add(myDataGridViewRow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I came to the same solution as well. You can't add a new row without defining the columns.

Comment: thats what i told, as i was not knowing whether you have defined the columns earlier or not, so i gave solution for both the cases :)

Answer (score 2):

A really nice solution was posted [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150524083441/http://bartonpaullevenson.com/CSPasteIntoGrid.html):

But, one line needs to be changed:

```
 if (dgv.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
            dgv.Rows.Add(r + rowsInClipboard.Length - dgv.Rows.Count);
```

needs to be changed to:

```
 if (dgv.Rows.Count < (r + rowsInClipboard.Length))
            dgv.Rows.Add(r + rowsInClipboard.Length+1 - dgv.Rows.Count);
```

If this line isn't changes, the last row pasted will not be passed to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are dealing with Unicode here is the code to paste to a DataTable that is binded to a the DataGridView

```
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetText().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                var temp = dt1.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                    temp[i] = pastedRowCells[i];
                dt1.Rows.Add(temp);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Another option to get Unicode working is to use `if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText))` and `o.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText)`

Answer (score 0):

The code below allows to paste clipboard data starting from the selected cell, ignores if data exceeds the current column count and adds subsequent rows if required to accommodate for extra pasted rows

```
private void dataBatch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        var gridView = (DataGridView)sender;
        DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
        {
            string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat).ToString().TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()), Environment.NewLine);
            DataGridViewCell firstSelectedCell;
            try
            {
                firstSelectedCell = gridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0 ? gridView.SelectedCells[0] : (gridView.Rows.Count > 0 ? ((DataGridViewRow)(gridView.Rows[0])).Cells[0] : throw new Exception(""));
            }
            catch { return; }
            int initialColumnIndex = firstSelectedCell.ColumnIndex;

            var rowCounter = 1;
            var rowCount = pastedRows.Count();

            foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
            {
                var cellData = pastedRow.Split('\t');
                foreach (var cd in cellData)
                {
                    firstSelectedCell.Value = cd;
                    firstSelectedCell.Selected = true;

                    if (firstSelectedCell.ColumnIndex < gridView.Columns.Count - 1)
                    {
                        firstSelectedCell = gridView[firstSelectedCell.ColumnIndex + 1, firstSelectedCell.RowIndex];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (rowCounter < rowCount)
                {
                    if (firstSelectedCell.RowIndex >= gridView.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        gridView.Rows.Add();
                    }
                    firstSelectedCell = gridView[initialColumnIndex, firstSelectedCell.RowIndex + 1];
                    rowCounter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've just modified [@Latheesan's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/22833914/) as below which is the shortest version.

```
DataObject o = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (o.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
{
    if (myDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
        myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
    if (myDataGridView.Columns.Count > 0)
        myDataGridView.Columns.Clear();

    bool columnsAdded = false;
    string[] pastedRows = Regex.Split(o.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().TrimEnd("\r\n".ToCharArray()), "\r\n");
    foreach (string pastedRow in pastedRows)
    {
        string[] pastedRowCells = pastedRow.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

        if (!columnsAdded)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
                myDataGridView.Columns.Add("col" + i, pastedRowCells[i]);

            columnsAdded = true;
            continue;
        }

        myDataGridView.Rows.Add(pastedRowCells);

        //***You don't need following lines, use just above line. ***

        //myDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        //int myRowIndex = myDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;

        //using (DataGridViewRow myDataGridViewRow = myDataGridView.Rows[myRowIndex])
        //{
        //    for (int i = 0; i < pastedRowCells.Length; i++)
        //        myDataGridViewRow.Cells[i].Value = pastedRowCells[i];
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. That or they weren't real thrilled with you copying another answer and not giving an attribution link.)

Comment: Thanks Nathan but that was my first comment. you would just say what I'd have done. This is a kind a rude action. I think. I did not tell in the comment that It's a new and best solution. I reviewed and tested @Latheesan's code. It did not work! I shared a better one...

Comment: That's not a problem; the problem is more that your answer didn't (sufficiently) clearly explain *why* Latheesan's code didn't work and why yours does, and it was also rather slapdash with attribution, as I mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

### //Column Count Bug Propered:://

```
using System.Linq;

DataTable xDataTable = new DataTable();
DataObject XClipboardDat = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();

if (XClipboardDat.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
{
    string[] XClipboardRows = Regex.Split(XClipboardDat.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString(), @"[\r\n]+").Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.ToString())).ToArray();

    IEnumerable<string[]> XDatRowCol = XClipboardRows.Select(xRow => Regex.Split(xRow, @"[\t]+").Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.ToString())).ToArray());

    int ColNum = XDatRowCol.Select(XDatRow => XDatRow.Length).ToArray().Max<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ColNum; i++) { xDataTable.Columns.Add(); }

    foreach(string[] XDatRow in XDatRowCol) { xDataTable.Rows.Add(XDatRow); }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = xDataTable;
 }
```