# C# Datagridview like Excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a software that uses a DataGridView.

I have an Excel spreadsheet from where I will copy a whole column at a time.
So, I need to click the first cell of the DataGridView (one click only, not double click) and hit CTRL + V to paste.

I need to add a row in the DataGrid for each pasted item and have the DataGridView add each Clipboard item to a row.

At the moment, I have a string that receives the text from the Clipboard and an array that receives each line from the Clipboard.

I need a help to use CTRL + V to paste the clipboard into each line.

**I need my DataGridView to work like Excel by adding and removing items easily.**

Thanks all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To help the community answer your question, please provide some sample code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: If your question can be reformulated to "How to paste excel data to datagridview", this existing question might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833327/pasting-excel-data-into-a-blank-datagridview-index-out-of-range-exception

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen. Through your help, I was able to do my work. It's just that I was not sure how to formalize my doubt in a text.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to intercept the key strokes, and check if it is CTRL+V.  Then add each line to your DataGrid. This will add everything to the bottom of the grid, you will need to think about how you want to implement how the data is added. It will look like this:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {

       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
       {

        //This is the name of your gridview.. just for show
       DataGridView dv = new DataGridView();
        // Your array of the clipboard.. for show
       string[] clipboardlines = new string[2];
           foreach(string line in clipboardlines)
           {
             this.dv.Rows.Add(line);
           }
       }
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```