# How to insert specific excel row into datagridview using excel rowindex

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5, excel-interop

I am performing search within excel `workbook` using small c# application
using below method

```
public void SearchExcelFiles(string FilePath)
{
    string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    if (!GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Text)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter text for search");
        return;
    }

    oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FilePath,   //---Filename OR FilePath
                             0,          //---object UpdateLinks
                             true,       //---object ReadOnly
                             Type.Missing,    //5//---object Format
                             "",         //---object Password
                             "",         //---object WriteResPassword
                             false,      //---object ReadOnlyRecommend
                             Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,     //---object Origin
                             "",         //---object Delimiter
                             true,       //---object Editable
                             false,      //---object Notify
                             0,          //---object Converter
                             true,       //---object AddToMru
                             false,      //---object Local
                             false);     //---object CorruptLoad;

    //specifying searching range within each excel sheet
    //Excel.Range oRng = oXL.get_Range("A1", "XFD1048576");
            Excel.Range xlCell = 
   xlWSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Range oRng = xlWSheet.get_Range("A1", 
   xlWSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing));

    //loop to search witin all excel sheets (workbook)
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet SheetID in oWB.Worksheets)
    {   //loop within all textboxs value to search if it is exist
        foreach (TextBox cont in GB_Search.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cont.Text))
            {
                currentFind = oRng.Find(cont.Text,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                                        Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                        Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                        Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                        false,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing);

                while (currentFind != null)
                {
                    //Keep track of the first range you find.
                    if (firstFind == null)
                    {
                        firstFind = currentFind;
                    }
                    //if current address is same as the starting address stop searching
                    else if (currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing) == firstFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    //keep searching for next value
                    currentFind = oRng.FindNext(currentFind);
                    MessageBox.Show(currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)); // for test purpose
                    string CurrentAddress = currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    AddToDataGridView(CurrentAddress, SheetID.Name, ConnStr); //when match found get full Row details and populate it to datagridview
                }
                //empty ranges before looking for the next textbox values
                firstFind = null;
                currentFind = null;
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("Done control..." + cont.Name); //~test Purpose
        }
        //MessageBox.Show("Done...sheet"); //~test Purpoes
    }
    //MessageBox.Show("Done...wb"); //~test Purpose
    oWB.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    oWB = null;
    oXL.Quit();
}
```

now when match found I am calling this method `AddToDataGridView()` which should do the following:

- Get full row details by using where clause (in somehow) the `rowid` shown at attached image
- populate this row and add to `datagridview`

another way to this are welcomed

```
    public void AddToDataGridView(string CurrentAddress, string SheetName, string ConnStr)
    {
        string cmdtxt = @"select * from [" + SheetName + "$" + CurrentAddress + "]Where ???? ";
        MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt); // test purpose
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtxt, conn);

            DA.Fill(dt);
            DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

[image]

**example**

```
----------------------------------------------------------
 # |     A     |      B      |      C      |      D      |
----------------------------------------------------------
 1 | A VALUE1  |   B VALUE1  |   C VALUE1  |   D VALUE1  |
----------------------------------------------------------
 2 | A VALUE2  |   B VALUE2  |   C VALUE2  |   D VALUE2  |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

suppose that `B VALUE2` is my searching match value... I want to get the rowid which is `2` in that case the query that row `select * from [sheet_Name$] where rowid=2` then add it to `datagridview` how to do that ?

thanks alot

Comment: I am having a difficult time understanding what you are asking. What little I can decipher is, you want to search an Excel workbook for some text that matches what the user types into a text box? I am clueless what you mean by… _”for each match found I am trying to get the full row details and the bounded into datagridview as shown but I am wondering what is the name of first row in excel file that shows series of ID NameOfRowID so I can use it as where clause show at attached iamge then bound that row into datagridview”_...????

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the previous statement? I can understand searching and finding the value in the Excel worksheet and returning which row and column it was found in… the rest… is unclear.

Comment: @JohnG I had update my post to included my last modification on it please if you wish to take a look... my problem that is not clear for you... is as you can see I am trying to get  the full row of matched value using select query now in the where clause syntax I should use `column_name' first what is the column name of that row shown at attached image the so I can use it to query that row and then populate it to `datagridview`... if it still unclear please I can help ... sorry for my bad English... thanks

Comment: @JohnG with small example at the last of my post hope it will help you to understand my case ... thanks

Comment: I am curious why you want to “query” the SAME Excel worksheet for the row that you already know… First, your “query" is malformed and is never executed, in addition, it will not work since the connection to the worksheet will fail because you already have the worksheet open. Questions… Are ALL the worksheets Identical in column structure? Does each worksheet have a header row (first row in the worksheet)?

Comment: In addition, to get the column structure of the Excel worksheet… you may want to look into Excel’s `UsedRange` property. The line in the code: `Excel.Range oRng = oXL.get_Range("A1", "XFD1048576");` simply grabs a large portion of the worksheet and you really have no idea if you are getting ALL the used cells. That is what `UsedRange` does… it returns a range that contains ALL the cells that contain data. Your current code will loop through many cells that have no values… which is unnecessary.

Comment: Using the `UsedRange` property AND if the columns have headers AND each sheet is exactly the same structure… Then, grab the `UsedRange` from the first worksheet and create a `DataTable` such that the columns in the `DataTable` will be the same number of columns returned from `UsedRange`. The name of each column would be the values from the FIRST row in the range returned from `UsedRange`. I can post an example if this is at least on the right track.

Comment: @JohnG I have not query anywork sheet I just open excel file then find desire matching string and I am trying to query 
only the matched row before this step I though I am working within the excel file according to my code.. am I right ? correct me if I am wrong 
and my code not working yet yes beacuse it is not clear to my how I am going to get that row and then populate it
I am still confused

Comment: @JohnG No, not all worksheets Identical in column structure?
yes, each worksheet have a header row but I wish to use column index inestaed because they dont Identical in column structure
for the `UsedRange` yes your expert opinion 100 % is correct, i will try to chnage my code if you can help me ..thanks alot

Comment: @JohnG waiting for your comments according to the answer of your question

Comment: @JohnG I have update my post to use `UsedRange` as you suggest please any recommendation about it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165762/discussion-between-johng-and-sam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without fully understanding, what the goal is here. The best I can sum up is to search for a string in an Excel workbook. You want the results of the search to be displayed in a `DataGridView`. From your comments, you stated that each worksheet may have a different column structure and you want the “complete” row that matched the search string in at least one of the cells in that row. Therefore, each worksheet search result may/will have a different column structure. I hope I understand this correctly.

If this is the case then I am hoping the code below may help. It is a simple form, that has a button to open/select an Excel workbook to search; a text box to allow the user to type the search string into; a combo box to hold the names of the worksheets in the selected workbook; a search button to initiate the search process; a textLog text box for debugging and finally a `DataGridView` to hold the search results. Throw in a few labels and it may look something like below after a search for “John” in the workbook “new293.xlsx”.

[image]

The text box on the right is used as a log output for testing if needed. After the search results come back, the user can use the combo box to select the results from each worksheet.

The code does a simple search for a string in a given workbook. When the user types something into the search text box and clicks the search button, the code opens the given workbook, searches for the target string in each worksheet and creates a `DataTable` to hold the successfully found rows. A `DataSet` is created to hold the “different” `DataTable`’s created by each worksheet since each worksheet may have a different column structure.

Below is a more detail description, however, I must comment about some possible Excel issues that may arise.

Currently the code will search for any substring of the target string. Example, if you searched for “a”, the returned results will contain ANY string with an “a” in it... “cat” “bat” etc. You may want to refine how this is done. Excels “Find” method may not be the best option. (more below)

When using Excels `UsedRange` property, it should be noted that this may return cells that will “appear” empty. In almost all cases when this happens, there is some formatting in the cell but the cell is empty and contains no data… `UsedRange` may include that cell in the range because of the formatting. Please be aware of this and do not be too quick to claim `UsedRange` is flawed when it returns these “apparently” empty cells. I have a solution for this in another answer.

Lastly, about Excel and interop… the current code uses the same Excel `Find` method as your posted code does. This should be fine if the dataset is not to large, however, if there is a large amount of data (large Excel worksheets with many columns and rows), this may become a performance problem. This is an Excel and interop issue. Calling methods like `UsedRange`, `Find` and others is VERY EXPENSIVE when used in a loop (which we are). Point being, if the worksheets are large, you may want to consider a different implementation without using interop. I understand there are better (free) third party Excel libraries.

With that said, below is the code to the form above.

Global variables in the form:

A `DataSet` `ds` to hold the `DataTables`; self-explanatory path `DefaultDirectory`; an Excel `workbook` to search and finally the Excel application itself.  Upon load, the Excel app is started and waits for the user to select a workbook.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
string DefaultDirectory = @"D:\Test\";
Workbook workbook;
Excel.Application excelApp;

public Form3() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  excelApp = new Excel.Application();
}
```

The open/select workbook button click to select a workbook uses an `OpenFileDialog` to allow the user to select the workbook to search. Once selected, the global variable `workbook` is open and available to other methods.

```
private void btnSelectWorkbook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DGV_Data.DataSource = null;
  tbSearch.Text = "";
  cbWorksheetNames.Items.Clear();
  textLog.Text = "";
  lblWorkbookName.Text = "";
  OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
  ofd.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
  ofd.InitialDirectory = DefaultDirectory;
  if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    string fileToOpen = ofd.FileName;
    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileToOpen);
    lblWorkbookName.Text = "Workbook: " + fileToOpen;
  }
}
```

After the user selects a workbook to search, and has typed some target text to search for… the user clicks the “Search” button. First, two checks are made to make sure there is some text to search for and also check if there is a workbook open to search in. If there is no text to search for or a workbook is not open, display a message to the user and return without searching.

If there is an open workbook and text to search for, the global `DataSet` `ds` is initialized, then `ds` is filled with each worksheet’s `DataTable` by calling the `GetRowsFromSearchStringFromAllWorksheets`. . After the `DataSet` has been filled (more below) the `DataGridView`’s `DataSource` is set to the first `DataTable` in the `DatatSet`; the combo box is filled with the worksheet names and finally some labels are updated.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbSearch.Text)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Enter text for search");
    return;
  }
  if (workbook == null) {
    MessageBox.Show("Select a workbook");
    return;
  }

  ds = new DataSet();
  try {
    ds = GetRowsFromSearchStringFromAllWorksheets(workbook, tbSearch.Text);
    DGV_Data.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    FillComboBoxWithSheetNames();
    cbWorksheetNames.SelectedIndex = 0;
    gbResults.Text = "Search Results for '" + tbSearch.Text + "'";
    tbSearch.Text = "";
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

The `GetRowsFromSearchStringFromAllWorksheets` method (which probably needs a better name) is not doing much. It loops through each worksheet in the workbook, creates a `DataTable` from the worksheet, fills the data table by calling the `FillTableWithSearchResults` method (below), then finally adds the `DataTable` to the `DataSet`. The `GetDTColumnsFromWorksheet` method (below) creates a `DataTable` based on what the header rows are in the worksheet. The first row in the worksheet is assumed to be header rows and uses these as column names for the `DataTable`. Note: currently, if the search returns with no results, the worksheet `DataTable` is STILL added to the `DataSet`. I left the debug code to modify if you only want to add worksheets that contained results.

```
private DataSet GetRowsFromSearchStringFromAllWorksheets(Workbook wb, string searchString) {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  foreach (Worksheet currentWorksheet in wb.Worksheets) {
    System.Data.DataTable currentDT = GetDTColumnsFromWorksheet(currentWorksheet);
    //textLog.Text += "Searching in worksheet " + currentWorksheet.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    FillTableWithSearchResults(currentWorksheet.UsedRange, searchString, currentDT);
    if (currentDT.Rows.Count > 0) {
      textLog.Text += "Matches found in worksheet " + currentWorksheet.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    else {
      textLog.Text += "No matches found in worksheet " + currentWorksheet.Name + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    ds.Tables.Add(currentDT);
  }
  return ds;
}
```

The `GetDTColumnsFromWorksheet` takes a worksheet and returns a `DataTable`. The data table returned will have the same number of columns as there are returned from “UsedRange` from the worksheet. An extra column is added to display where in the worksheet the cell is found. It is in an RXXCXX format in the first column. If a cell in a column in the used range has no value, the string “???XX” will be used. This is for cases where there is an empty column.

```
private System.Data.DataTable GetDTColumnsFromWorksheet(Worksheet ws) {
  // this assumes that row 1 of the worksheet contains a row header
  // we will use this to name the `DataTable` columns
  // this also assumes there are no "lingering" cells with values
  // that may not necessarily belong to the data table
  int missingColumnNameCount = 1;
  Range usedRange = ws.UsedRange;
  int numberOFColumns = usedRange.Columns.Count;
  System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
  dt.TableName = ws.Name;
  string currentColumnHeader = "";
  Range row1;
  // add an extra column in the front
  // this column will show where (RXCX) the found item is in the worksheet
  dt.Columns.Add("CXRX", typeof(string));
  for (int i = 1; i <= numberOFColumns; i++) {
    row1 = usedRange[1, i];
    if (row1.Value2 != null) {
      currentColumnHeader = row1.Value2.ToString();
    }
    else {
      // if the row has no value a default name and indexer to avoid duplicate column names
      currentColumnHeader = "???" + missingColumnNameCount;
      missingColumnNameCount++;
    }
    dt.Columns.Add(currentColumnHeader, typeof(string));
  }
  return dt;
}
```

The `FillTableWithSearchResults` method takes a range to search through, a string to search for and finally a data table to add the successful searches to. The `DataTable` passed in has already been created and the columns have been initialized.

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle Excels `Find/FindNext` methods. Therefore, I hope I have this correct. When the `Find` is used on a range for the first time, it returns the first found cell that matches what it is searching for. This retuned range is a cell address of the “first” found item. From my understanding, the `FindNext` will obviously return the NEXT found item. The issue is that when it finds the LAST item and searches for the next one, it simply starts over at the beginning. Therefore, the stopping condition for the loop would be when the cell address of the `NextFind` matches the cell address of the “first” `Find`. This will require that we save the “first” `Find`’s cell address. Below is one approach to this conundrum.

Create two ranges: one `startRange` to hold the starting “first” `Find`, another `currentRange` to hold the currently “found” range. First, a check is made to make sure there is something to search in. If there is at least one row to search in, the `startRange` is set from the “first” `Find`. This is the cell address we need to stop at when using `FindNext`. If there is at least one item found, then we can search for the next one and enter the `FindNext` loop. Simply set `currentRange` to the `NextFind` add the `startRange` from the “first” `Find`to the data table then finally enter the `FindNext` loop such that it will continue using `FindNext` and adding new rows to the data table until the `currentRange` cell address `Equals` the `startingRange` cell address. This indicates that `FindNext` has looped back to the beginning and the search is complete. The `AddExcelRowToDataTable` adds the found row to the data table (below).

Note: currently this code allows duplicate entries in cases where the searched for string is found in more than one column in the same row. There will be one row entry in the grid for every found search string in the rows columns. Example: if row 5 has the searched for string in columns 4, 6 and 8, there will be a row for R5C4, R5C6 and R5C8. I did not filter this to remove duplicate rows.

```
private void FillTableWithSearchResults(Range usedRange, string searchString, System.Data.DataTable dt) {
  Range currentRange;
  if (usedRange.Rows.Count > 0) {
    Range startRange = usedRange.Find(searchString);
    if (startRange != null) {
      currentRange = usedRange.FindNext(startRange);
      AddExcelRowToDataTable(usedRange, startRange, dt);
      string startAddress = startRange.get_Address(true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1);
      while (!currentRange.get_Address(true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1).Equals(startAddress)) {
        AddExcelRowToDataTable(usedRange, currentRange, dt);
        currentRange = usedRange.FindNext(currentRange);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `AddExcelRowToDataTable` method takes a used range to get the data from, a range `row` to add to the third given parameter `DataTable`. Again a little hacky, a check is made to make sure that there are not more columns in the used range than there are in the data table. A row Index is obtained to indicate which row in the used range to add to the data table. A `DataRow` `dr` is created from the given `DataTable` `dt` to make sure the column schemas are the same. The first column is going to be the column we added earlier to display the RXXCXX location column of the found item. Add the extra column data then loop through the rest of the columns adding the worksheet values to the `DataRow`. After the all the column values have been added, the `DataRow` is added to the `DataTable`.

```
private void AddExcelRowToDataTable(Range usedRange, Range row, System.Data.DataTable dt) {
  if (usedRange.Columns.Count >= dt.Columns.Count - 1) {
    int rowIndex = GetRowIndexOfFoundItem(row);
    if (rowIndex >= 0) {
      DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
      // add the CXRX data
      dr[0] = row.get_Address(true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1);
      for (int i = 1; i <= usedRange.Columns.Count; i++) {
        dr[i] = usedRange.Cells[rowIndex, i].Value2;
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
  }
}
```

The `GetRowIndexOfFoundItem` takes a cell range and returns the (int) row index from the cells string RXXCXX address.

```
private int GetRowIndexOfFoundItem(Range range) {
  // hacky ... the string is a format of RXXCX or RXXcXXX or RXXXXCXX.
  // we want the XXX after the R... split the string on 'C'
  // to get RXX..X, then remove the 'R' and parse the number
  string RCaddress = range.get_Address(true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1);
  string[] split = RCaddress.Split('C');
  RCaddress = split[0].Remove(0, 1);
  int rowIndex = 0;
  if (int.TryParse(RCaddress, out rowIndex)) {
    return rowIndex;
  }
  else {
    // not valid number
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Method to fill the combo box with worksheet names after the search has finished.

```
private void FillComboBoxWithSheetNames() {
  cbWorksheetNames.Items.Clear();
  foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {
    cbWorksheetNames.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
  }
}
```

The combo boxes `SelectedIndexChnged` event is wired up and uses the combo boxes selected index to determine which `DataTable` to display in the grid.

```
private void cbWorksheetNames_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DGV_Data.DataSource = ds.Tables[cbWorksheetNames.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Finally some resource cleanup.

```
private void Form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
  try {
    if (workbook != null) {
      workbook.Close();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    }
    excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
  }
}
```

Sorry for the long winded answer, I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks John I really appreciate your kind help you share with me a lot of your experiences... that is was very helpful

Comment: one last question from your experiences I need way to encrypt my code ?

Comment: Glad the code helped ;-) Encrypting your code sounds like a different question. However, encryption is a common task and a google search should provide many examples and theory about it. I am guessing it should not be difficult to encrypt your code… I have to ask… why do you need to encrypt your “code”? I am familiar with encrypting “data”. Less familiar with encrypting the source code but I am guessing it would be similar. Again, I am curious as to why you would need to do this.

Comment: thank there is no actual reason to encrypt code... It just to now how :D thanks you Mr.John ill do Google search I ask just to get something from your experience

Answer (score 0):

First, you are only finding the "first" row in each sheet because it is searching for a named range called `TB_First_Name.Text` in each sheet - there can only be at most one of those in each sheet.

Secondly, there seems to be a typo in your code - I believe `DataGridView gdv_data = new DataGridView();` should be `DataGridView DGV_data = new DataGridView();`

Finally, seems from other answers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044387/3661120) the best way to populate a datagridview row from excel would  be this kind of way:

```
var rowArray = oRng.Cells.Value2.Cast<object>().ToArray();
try { j = d.CurrentRow.Index; } catch { }
DataGridViewRow r = new DataGridViewRow();
r.CreateCells(d, rowArray);
DGV_Data.Rows.Insert(j, r);
```

Comment: sorry `TB_First_Name.Text` is just name ... this textbox repersent search string among all sheets within a `workbook` but when the string has match i am getting the rowid then what i want to do is to inset row into `datagridview` .... for now I am working on solution  may success is about converting the `rowid` to the column name then query the row example `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24]`... finally update my post to change the textbox name ..thanks

Comment: This is how your "search" is happening: `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng = GetSpecifiedRange(TB_search_text.Text, SheetID);` - this can only find one per sheet

Comment: your are right but at the end of `if statement` i used `oRng = oRng.FindNext(oRng);` so it should go to next match ... am I right ?

Comment: No, that seems to find the next occurrence of a value in a range after the given argument (which is supposed to be a cell).  If you want to use that you should use the `Find` method to find `TB_search_text` the first time, then use `FindNext` to find the next occurrence.  Using `GetSpecifiedRange` returns a named range with the argument as the name.