# How to read a rows with column name "Path" in .xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have a `.xlsx` File. In that file I have a column with name `"Path"` and it is the last column. The values of this column contains the path to the excel files which I have to open using `xlrd` package.

I want to do is read the first path (row) open the workbook and do the task. Then increment the row number, read the next path(row) and the again do the same task.

Along with this I have to print the value row number which is changing after every loop and column number which will remain same every time because we are only reading from `"Path"` column.

So far I am able to fetch out the value of the row but the problem is I am not able extract the number or index of the row and column (cell) which it is reading from.

Secondly is there any better way to do it.

Here is the code which I am trying:
Remember `Path` is last column of the sheet.

```
pathbook = open_workbook("S:\\1. DIRECTORY MASTER\\FINANCIAL RESEARCH\\Financial Data Initiative\\Database - "
                         "TEST\\Cost Detail Data Tracker.xlsx")
pathbook_sheet = pathbook.sheet_by_name("Document Location")
data = []
for row in range(5, 6):
    for col in range(pathbook_sheet.ncols):
       elm = pathbook_sheet.cell_value(row, col)
       print(row,col)
    data.append(elm)

for file in data:
    for i in range(1, get_numberofmilestone()):
        list_sheets = ['Labour M' + str(i), 'Travel M' + str(i), 'Equip M' +
        str(i), 'Consult-SubC M' + str(i),
                'Other M' + str(i)]
        Empty_List = []

        pathbook = open_workbook(file)
        pathbook_sheet = pathbook.sheet_by_name("Labour M" + str(i))
```

Comment: read the answer about similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871143/how-to-insert-specific-excel-row-into-datagridview-using-excel-rowindex)

Comment: I am beginner to python. Its very hard to understand for me what you preferred @sam